# Java process in linux needs initial warmup

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

we have a legacy java multithreaded process on a RHEL 6.5 which is very time critical (low latency), and it processes hundreds of thousands of message a day. It runs in a powerful Linux machine with 40cpus.  What we found is the process has a high latency when it process the first 50k messages with average of 10ms / msg , and after this 'warmup' time, the latency starts to drop and became about 7ms, then 5ms and eventually stops at about 3-4ms / second at day end.

this puzzles me , and one of possibility that i can think of is maps are being resized at the beginning till it reaches a very big capacity - and it just doesn't exceed the load factor anymore.  From what I see, the maps are not initialized with initial capacity - so that is why i say that may be the case. I tried to put it thru profiler and pump millions of messages inside, hoping to see some 'resize' method from the java collections, but i was unable to find any of them. It could be i am searching for wrong things, or looking into wrong direction. As a new joiner and existing team member left, i am trying to see if there are other reasons that i haven't thought of.

Another possibility that i can think of is kernel settings related, but i am unsure what it could be.

I don't think it is a programming logic issue, because it runs in acceptable speed after the first 30k-50k of messages.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there heavy disk activity during the 'warm up' that then tapers off?  I wonder if you are seeing your cache get populated.

Comment: Does your application do some static data lookup, after 40-50k messages almost entire static data loads up. If such is the case you can pre-load such caches

Comment: The application growing time might be there: Heap growth, Cache growth, you can also take a look at GC behavior

Comment: How many threads are active at any one time? Do you have any expense related to thread spawning, etc.  I am not sure that this is relevant, but it's my only thought beyond those above.  Could you try spawning your thread pool before you start processing the messages.  Also - what happens if you limit the number of threads???? I suspect you might find a pattern that may help.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? HotSpot technology has been in the VM for a long time so even if you Java app is "legacy" it probably has this dynamic optimizer called HotSpot inside it, that compiles your bytecode to native code after it has gathered enough information about how your application runs. And it keeps doing this while the application runs. This is completely normal behaviour for any Java server application - it's surprising the none of the comments have mentioned this yet.

Comment: There is no heavy disk activity, based on Sar. It does not do any lazy loading either of static data cache either. There were no Full GC, only minor GCs. The health is growing, but we give a sufficient heap size which is more than enough for it to run. From the profiling log, there were no thread contention issues, (eg. no thread were blocked). it has about 2k threads at a time. Lastly, It is using JDK 7.

Comment: @Erwin - i think you may be on the right track, i started looking into that just now, about tiered compilation. The next thing i will be trying is to print the log compilation and see what it is doing. I also just downloaded jitwatch also. Thanks.

Comment: There are many publications on this; maybe this one from Oracle is a nice intro: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#3

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it takes some time for the operating system to realize that your application is a big resource consumer. So after few seconds it sees that there is a lot of activity with files of your application, and only then the operating system deals with the activity by populating the cache and action like this.